# join 3 mysql tables with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

im having 3 tables

```
product
-product_id
-name
-image

product_description
-product_id
-product_description
-product_attributes

product_store
-product_id
-store_id
```

what i need to do is get the product name, description and image from the `product` and `product_description` tables and the products should be only from the `product_store` table where the `store_id = 0 or 1`.

the `product_store` table has only the `product_id` and `store_id` fields

so far i have joined the product and product_description tables. But im still trying to join the `product_store` table to check if the products comes from the correct store.

```
SELECT p.product_id, pd.name,p.image FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) order by p.product_id DESC LIMIT 3
```

can anyone tell me how can i join the 3rd table and check if its from the correct store_id?

Comment: give me the field name clearly pls, cant understand your details..

Comment: According to your table description above the table `product_description` does not have a column `name`. You might want to change your statement to `p.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the 3rd table in the party (I mean JOIN), like this:

```
SELECT p.product_id, pd.name,p.image 
FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN product_description pd 
ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
JOIN product_store ps
ON (p.product_id = ps.product_id AND ps.store_id IN (0,1))
ORDER BY p.product_id DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct p.product_id, d.name, p.image
from product p join product_description d on
  p.product_id = d.product_id join product_store s on
  p.product_id = s.product_id
where
  s.store_id in (0, 1)
order by p.product_id DESC LIMIT 3
```

The `DISTINCT` is necessary as you might join with `product_store` twice, and duplicate rows.